# Messagebox is displayed multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, messagebox, gestures

I am using Kinect to develop an Image viewing application using C# and WPF. When the user puts both his hand above his head, I am displaying a `Messagebox` asking the user if he/she really wants to quit:

```
    //Quit if both hands above head
    if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y &&
        skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y)
    {
        pause = true;
        quit();
    }
```

The `quit()` function is as follows:

```
    private void quit()
    {
        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
        MessageBoxImage image = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Close V'Me :(", button, image);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes) window.Close();
        else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            pause = false;
        }

    }
```

The `pause` variable is used to stop recognizing any gestures while the `MessageBox` is still active. (`pause` = `false` means gesture recognition active, else no.)

So there are two problems:

1. The `MessageBox` is displayed twice. If I click `Yes` in any one of those, the `window` closes. The behavior is okay but I dont want two windows.
2. If I click `No`, another `MessageBox` gets displayed. If I click `No` on this box, another opens. This happens for every successive `No` that I click. After getting displayed 5-6 times approximately, it gives me the behavior I want, i.e, it changes the value of the `pause` variable to `false` and thus activates the recognition of other gestures.

What exactly am I doing wrong? What can I do to stop EVERYTHING and wait for the user to click on one of the options? Also why is the `MessageBox` being displayed multiple times (Twice initially, and more when I click `No`)?

Comment: Possibly this is because quit() is synchron. So if the event happens while the code processes quit() it will probably query the event of the hands being somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont exactly know what a synchronous method is. The issue however is resolved. Thank you :)

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489581/c-sharp-and-kinect-gesture-time

Comment: @Kinected You could say its similar but in no way an exact duplicate. I've used a flag to stop displaying the `messagebox` multiple times unlike the guy who asked that question. The reason I asked this question was, even after using a flag I got the `messagebox` multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without looking at the code being debugged, but I'm guessing that your first block of code is being called in some sort of loop or event handler that is processing the latest Kinect data.

**Check for pause**

Try adding something like this above the first bit of code:

```
if (pause)
   return;

if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y &&
    skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y)
{
    pause = true;
    quit();
}
```

**Timeout**

If this doesn't work, you might need to add a timeout period since the last time you prompt the user.

```
private void quit()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastQuitTime).TotalSeconds > 5)
    {

          //Prompt the user

          //Reset the timeout
          _lastQuitTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Its being used in a handler (`OnSkeletonFrameReady`) which checks if the `SkeletonFrame` is ready.

And the first solution that you gave worked out flawlessly! But I am still clueless as to what it changed and what was wrong initially.

Comment: @KaranThakkar - Initially, you were setting pause to true, but you weren't using that value at prevent showing the dialog again.

Comment: So let me get this straight. What `return` does is, it breaks out of the handler and enters into it again?

Comment: return exits the current method.  It's the same as wrapping the rest of your code in that method with if (!pause) { if (skeleton.Joints...  }

Comment: Looks like you have a race condition. Just to shore it up, you might want to add in synchronization when accessing the pause variable.

Comment: @MikeBrown Ummm, I actually dont know what synchronisation is. Perhaps you could point me to someplace where I could read it up and revamp my code to include it?

Comment: Synchronization is a technique for dealing with data that can be accessed by multiple threads (which is what is happening in your example). Multi-threaded programming is a very deep topic. If you want to dive down that rabbit hole, a good place to start is the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx). For specifics on Synchronization see [this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything that prevents calling of quit method twice, in your code. Just set a global variable to true at the begining of quit method, and set again to false at the end, and   check if it's false before calling quit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess at how this code works, but try this:

```
//Quit if both hands above head
if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y &&
    skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y &&
    !pause)
{
    pause = true;
    quit();
}
else
{
    pause = false;
}

...

private void quit()
{
    MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
    MessageBoxImage image = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Close V'Me :(", button, image);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes) window.Close();
    else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        pause = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this solution @KendallFrey but it only increased the problem. Now I get all those 5-6 windows in one go, instead of the previous version where I got each new window once I click `No`.